# NSMutableAttributedString Append in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I need to append 2 NSMutableAttributedString for my UITextview when user selection different words like the example.

string =  @"blabla1 blabla2 blabla3"

in first time the user select @"blabla1"

and the text looks like that @"**blabla1** blabla2 blabla3"

and after I select @"blabla3" the result I want to get in My UITextview is @"**blabla1** blabla2 **blabla3**"

now the result I get is @"**blabla1** blabla2 blabla3 blabla1 blabla2 **blabla3**"

that my code :

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)getNSMutableAttributedString:(NSString*)string withRange:(NSRange)range withTextView:(UITextView*)textView
{
if (!str)
{
    str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];

}
else
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [mutableAttString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];

    NSMutableAttributedString *first = str;
    NSMutableAttributedString *second = mutableAttString;

    NSMutableAttributedString* result = [first mutableCopy];
    [result appendAttributedString:second];

    str = result;

}

return str;
}
```

Comment: Do you want just to bold some part, or do you want to append? It's unclear with your "I need" and "I get".

Comment: Are there always 3 words?

Comment: no, its a free writing  textView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes can be added multiply times to one string.And you create a new attributedString from string, which don't have attributes.
In result you receive @"**blabla1** blabla2 blabla3 blabla1 blabla2 **blabla3**"

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*)getNSMutableAttributedString:(NSMutableAttributedString*)string withRange:(NSRange)range withTextView:(UITextView*)textView
{
if (!str)
 {
    str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:string];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];
 }
else
  {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];
  }
return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is get `str` (the existing `attributedText` from the `UITextView`) and then add an attribute to the specific range

```
str = [textView attributedText];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(range.location, range.length)];

return str;
```

What you are doing is creating a new attributed string with the same content but different attributes and then appending to the existing attributedText. That is why you see the text repeated twice.